# MVC validation RequiredIfTrue doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my View I have a dropdownlistfor. The dropdownlist has 5 options. The last option is 'Custom'. When this one is selected, two textboxfor's will be shown.

My model:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public DateType DateType { get; set; }

    public List<TypeDTO> DateTypesDTO { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue("Custom", ErrorMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht")]
    public DateTime? CustomDateFrom { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue("Custom", ErrorMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht")]
    public DateTime? CustomDateTo { get; set; }

    public bool Custom { get; set; }
}
```

Part of my View:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Tijdsinterval</label>
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateType, new SelectList(Model.DateTypesDTO, "DateType", "Translation"), new { id = "timespan", name = "timespan" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group hide" id="custom">
    <label class="control-label">Van</label>
    <div class="controls controls-margin">
        <div class="input-append datetimepicker">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomDateFrom, new { id = "datetimepicker", @class = "add-on", type = "text", data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomDateFrom)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Custom);
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label">Tot</label>
    <div class="controls controls-margin">
        <div class="input-append datetimepicker">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomDateTo, new { id = "datetimepicker", @class = "add-on", type = "text", data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomDateTo)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#partial-view').on('change', '#timespan', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Custom') {
                $('#custom').show();
            } else {
                $('#custom').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that in the Controller `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is always true, even if the two textboxes are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you set 'Custom' to true?

Comment: I don't do it anymore.
I did it first in JQuery in the onchange function but then I get a exception that the `Model` = null.
I don't know where to do this.

Comment: `if ($(this).val() == 'Custom') { $('#custom').show(); @Model.Custom = true; }` 
`else { $('#custom').hide(); @Model.Custom = false; }`

Comment: You don't have "DateType" property in ReportModel class.

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't show all the code, because not all code is relevant. And i forgot to show DateType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried almost everything, but it works now!

The Model:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public DateType DateType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CustomDateFrom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CustomDateTo { get; set; }

    public List<TypeDTO> DateTypesDTO { get; set; }
}
```

Part of the View:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Tijdsinterval</label>
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateType, new SelectList(Model.DateTypesDTO, "DateType", "Translation"), new { id = "timespan", name = "timespan" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group hide" id="custom">
    <label class="control-label">Van</label>
    <div class="controls controls-margin datetimepicker">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomDateFrom, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "add-on", data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomDateFrom)
    </div>
    <label class="control-label">Tot</label>
    <div class="controls controls-margin datetimepicker">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomDateTo, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "add-on", data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomDateTo)
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#partial-view').on('change', '#timespan', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Custom') {
                $('#custom').show();
            } else {
                $('#custom').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem was this: (see the question)

```
    <div class="controls controls-margin">
        <div class="input-append datetimepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
```

After i solved this problem, I had a lot of trouble with the validation of the datetime. And the problem was this line of code: `data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"`. The validator gives an `ErrorMessage`: 'The field CustomDateFrom must be a date.'

Now I just only send the date and not the hours: `data_format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`

Comment: if you changed dd-MM-yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy this should allow the date format to be accepted. I had a similar issue and this is how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying the fields are required if `Custom` is true. The problem is that nowhere is `Custom` every set to anything, so it will default to false and the fields will never be required. The selected value will be set in `DateType`, so you can pretty easily solve the problem by creating a custom getter for you `Custom` property:

```
public bool Custom
{
    get { return DateType == "Custom"; }
}
```